# How to extract given PDF to text and tables using python and store the data in .csv file?

Tags: python, ghostscript, data-extraction, pypdf

I need to extract the first table account number, branch name, etc and last table date, description, and amount.

pdf file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b537hdTUMQwWSOJHRan6ckHBUDhRBbvX/view?usp=sharing
getting blank output using pypdf2 library.
camelot giving OSError: Ghostscript is not installed.

```
import PyPDF2
file_path =open(r"E:\user\programs\28_oct_bank_statement\demo.pdf", "rb")
pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file_path)
pageObj = pdf.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
```

```
import camelot

data = camelot.read_pdf(r"demo.pdf", pages='all')
print(data)
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: sometimes PDF may have very complex structure (ie. it may keep every char as separated object) and programs have problem to get data from PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Camelot has dependancies that needs to be install in order to work, such as Ghoscript. You'll fist need to check if that is installed correctly for mac/ubuntu:

```
from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library("gs")
"libgs.so.9"
```

for windows:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library
find_library("".join(("gsdll", str(ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_voidp) * 8), ".dll")))
<name-of-ghostscript-library-on-windows>
```

otherwise download Ghostscript from the following page https://ghostscript.com/ for windows.I highly suggest reading through the camelot documentation again If you run into more issues.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the apache tika to do this.

[As shown here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parsing-pdfs-in-python-with-tika/)

You can simply install it and then with a python script:

```py
from tika import parser  
  
parsed_pdf = parser.from_file("sample.pdf")
  
text = parsed_pdf['content']
metadata = parsed_pdf['metadata']
print(data)
```

Note you do need Java installed on the machine for it to run, however it will return the test and then once you have the text you can look to identify a pattern within the text to extract the exact data required.

The nice part about this is it will also return the metadata of the pdf